# How can I return a view to its original state after animating it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I have a rectangular view with two labels (one static, one dynamic) set from a xib.
When the user touches the view, I have it contract and hide the labels (using `UIView`'s `-animateWithDuration: animations:`).

Is there any way I can save the context of just the view, and return to it later?

I know there is `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` but the documentation just says: **Returns graphics context** which I am guessing is the entire view. (What horrible documentation!)

It seems this is possible and common with `CALayers`, but this is just a `UIView` method and I'm not sure if it uses `CALayers` in its implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to answer a few of your questions:

Firstly, `UIView` is at its core a wrapper for a `CALayer`. You can get access to the underlying `CALayer` through the view's `layer` property. If you're doing a lot of animation work you'll probably find this very useful at some point. A 'graphics context', in the iOS sense of the word, is basically a place where information about the current drawing state is stored.

The convenience methods that `UIView` provides for animation (`animateWithDuration`, etc) automatically set the frame, bounds, etc of the view to their newly animated values once the animation has completed. You'll therefore want to keep hold of whatever values you are changing so you can animate back to them when required. Note that this *might not* just be the frame - if you're changing the alpha values you'll want to hang on to them as well, etc etc.

There are other options that you can try, but they involve using the slightly lower-level Core Animation APIs. This existing StackOverflow question has a really good summary: [UIView animations with Autoreverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040494/objective-c-ios-development-animations-autoreverse)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't easily save and restore the entire view and subview contents. `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` can be used to take a picture of a `UIView`, but not to save the subview locations.

Instead keep two sets of frames for every subview and then switch between them by setting `mySubview.frame`.

Comment: Yup, saving and restoring the frames for your view and any subviews should be easy and do what you want. Deeper CA trickery shouldn't be necessary.